# Rails 3.1: Dynamic linking to images in the asset pipeline?

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have ~ 500+ flag images that I previously kept in `public/images/flags/` and `public/images/flags_small/`. For each country in my Country model, I store the `:iso_code`, which is the same as the name of the flag image that corresponds to it. For example, mx.png is the name of the Mexican flag because mx is the two-letter ISO code for Mexico.

I previously had a helper method that would return the html to display the image based on the iso code of the country and whether I wanted the large or small flag.

With Rails 3.1, to comply with the asset pipeline, I'm under the impression that those images should  go into the `app/assets/images` folder. Following from this:

1. Can I maintain the subfolders therein?
2. How do I use image_tag to display the appropriate images?

**Edit: solution**
The answer below was correct, but I didn't want to type that much code each time,so I created two helper methods:

```
  def flag(country)
    image_tag('/assets/flags/' + country.iso_code.downcase + '.png')
  end

  def small_flag(country)
    image_tag('/assets/flag_small/' + country.iso_code.downcase + '.png')
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, you can
2. For example: `<%= image_tag 'flags/uk.gif' %>`

Comment: That doesn't work. It returns the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/flags/uk.png"):`

Comment: Duh. That's because there's no uk.png. It's gb.png. :) Thanks, your code works.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution to load images dynamically for Rails 5 (from a resource other than assets pipeline), imagine you have a controller called **car**.

1. add a new action (e.g. our action is called **image**) in your controller;

   ```
   def image
      path = "C:/pics/.../test.jpg" # just a sample path to test
      send_file path, :content_type => 'image/jpg', :disposition => 'inline'
   end
   ```
2. add the new route to your action in routes.rb;

   ```
   get '/img', to: "car#image"
   ```
3. and finally in your ERB file, create an image tag with;

   ```
   <div>
       <%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "home", :action => "image") %>
   </div>
   ```

This is just to test the basics and you can make it parametrized (to load the image based on id, name, etc.)